HttpClient to slow downloading image from url
Im trying to download an image from a url but C# HttpClient takes 21 seconds in this example but that same link on the browser like safari loads almost instantly.
I have created a simple test and running in debug I takes 21 seconds to download the image.
HttpClientHandler hch = new HttpClientHandler();
hch.Proxy = null;
hch.UseProxy = false; 

HttpClient imageRequest = new HttpClient(hch);
imageRequest.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "*/*");
imageRequest.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Python-urllib/3.10");
try
{
    var response = await imageRequest.GetAsync(new Uri("https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61OJ6NBYNWS.jpg"));

}
catch
{
    return;
}

I have tried playing around with headers ( accept/user agent) and different methods like GetByteArrayAsync but all of them take the same time to get the image.
I have also tried var response = await imageRequest.GetAsync(new Uri("https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61OJ6NBYNWS.jpg"),HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead); but it still takes 21 second with this link, some links never return.

Caanot reproduce https://dotnetfiddle.net/fNaRSG it takes 0.3 seconds.

Mm that’s curious, I’m starting to think it’s related to the net version, I forgot to say that I’m using C# in a windows forms project updated to net 8.0

The fiddle is .NET 8. Might be an issue with task scheduling in WinForms, what happens if you add ConfigureAwait(false) to all the awaits?

Don't rush to assume HttpClient has performance issues. It's used in all .NET Core applications that make any kind of HTTP request so a 6300% delay would be noticed. It's far more likely this is a networking issue, server-side or ISP throttling, or even an OS settings issue. You mention Safari which means you're probably using MacOS. Have you tried this on other machines?

Charlieface, have tried that to but the result is the same. Panagiotis, yes im using a Mac for development of the app but the issue persists in production on numerous windows machines but after testing maybe is the ISP like you said because I have started to notice that the problem goes away in the evening and returns in the morning, something I haven't notice since I only work in the morning, but still strange, maybe it has something to do with the network but still I don't understand why only the Http request is being slowed down.

Right now if I run var response = await imageRequest.GetAsync("https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61OJ6NBYNWS.jpg"); It takes 20 seconds sometimes an sometimes it times out at 100 secs,  but yesterday in the evening, same network and code it ran in like 0.305 seconds
